# Is it possible to imply the name of the parameters of a params array using the nameof operator?

Tags: c#, nameof

I thought I could make use of the new c# 6 operator nameof to build a dictionary of key/values implicitly from a params array.

As an example, consider the following method call:

```
string myName = "John", myAge = "33", myAddress = "Melbourne";
Test(myName, myAge, myAddress);
```

I am not sure there will be an implementation of Test that will be able to imply the name of the elements, from the params array.

Is there a way to do this using just `nameof`, without reflection ?

```
private static void Test(params string[] values)
{
    List<string> keyValueList = new List<string>();

    //for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    foreach(var p in values)
    {
        //"Key" is always "p", obviously
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {nameof(p)}, Value: {p}");
    }
}
```

Comment: `nameof` is a compiler time facility, not a runtime one.

Comment: There's no need for `myName`, `myAge`, etc. to exist in the compiled IL. If it doesn't exist, it can't be got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You don't have any knowledge of the variables names used. Such information is not passed to the callee.

You could achieve what you want like this:

```
private static void Test(params string[][] values)
{
    ...
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myName = "John", myAge = "33", myAddress = "Melbourne";
    Test(new string[] { nameof(myName), myName });
}
```

Or using a dictionary:

```
private static void Test(Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    ...
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myName = "John", myAge = "33", myAddress = "Melbourne";
    Test(new Dictionary<string, string> { { nameof(myName), myName }, { nameof(myAge), myAge} });
}
```

Or using `dynamic`:

```
private static void Test(dynamic values)
{
    var dict = ((IDictionary<string, object>)values);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic values = new ExpandoObject();
    values.A = "a";
    Test(values);
}
```

Another possibility would be the use of an `Expression`, which you pass in to the method. There you could extract the variable name from the expression and execute the expression for its value.

Comment: I am using a dictionary, I just thought of creating an overload that was "smarter".

Comment: Okay, expressions may come in handy. But more as a last resort I think.

Comment: If you want something "smarter" use and anonymous type and convert to a dictionary or a namevaluecollection

Comment: @MatthewWhited that's an option too. Couldn't get it working with an anonymous type (guess I was too lazy to write the reflection for it), but `dynamic` will do.